# How can I highlight better the edges I select

Tags: edit-mode

I am wondering is there a setting where I can choose to 'thicken' the selected edge in edit mode.
I want to do a FILL in a particular area which has multiple edges and so I hold the shift key and try to select all the edges around that area to fill.
Problem is (for me) is that with my poor eyesight I find it difficult to see what edges I have already selected - see image below with some edges already selected but hard to see.

[image]

Comment: Edit > Preferences > Themes > 3D viewport.... scroll all the way down to see "Edge Width"

Comment: As far as I know you can only set the colors differently, but the edge width only in general no matter if selected or not...

Comment: Thanks.  Yes can change the color but couldn't not see how to change edge width (only outline width which has no effect) although other eg vertex (size) can be changed.  It would be good if edge (selected) width could be changed.  Is that be possibility in a future version?

Comment: What Blender version are you using? mine is 3.6 and there is an Edge Width See the image https://imgur.com/a/CwFOyow

Comment: I am using 3.1 and AFAIK certain addons (for output of MSFS gLTF) only work up to  version 3.1.  I will check with the MSFS (Blender) forums.